# Orchard-Google analytics not generating demographics report after adding "ga(‘require’, ‘displayfeatures’);" in tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, orchardcms

I am using orchard for my site as per Google Analytics to track age and gender report I have added `ga(‘require’, ‘displayfeatures’);` to tracking code. They said it will take 24 hrs to generate report but last 2 days almost 48 hrs passed away but still it not generating it.

How we can do it by other way? or any changes in tracking code.

Comment: Did you remember to enable display features in the property settings ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff yes I have enabled that!!